# Missing CA certificates on OpenShift WordPress cartridge

Tags: security-certificate, wordpress

I am trying to use a WordPress theme named "X" on an OpenShift WordPress cartridge.

While installing an "Extension" through the "X" theme configuration page I get the following error:

> Downloading install package from `https://www.gamblify.com/wp-content/themes/x/framework/plugins/x-shortcodes.zip`…
>   Download failed. Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates.

I think my certificate is installed correctly (I used the OpenShift web interface), since the website works fine using Firefox or Chrome.

How can I update my WordPress cartridge with the correct CA certificates?

Note that gamblify.com currently doesn't point to the WordPress site in question.

Comment: I can't reach the server with HTTPS, port 443 is closed. Are you sure, the URL is correct?

Comment: As I noted in the question gamblify.com currently doesn't point to the WordPress server, since it is not working as per this question.